# About News Sitemap?

Tags: sitemap

In a News sitemap, we need to include URLs for all our articles, but only from the last three days. we shouldn't include older articles. Why we shouldn't old articles and if we keep the old articles what would happen?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your talking about the XML sitemap for the crawling engine like google?
Yes, you can keep the old articles, even more, this is preferable.

Comment: I was talking about News Sitemap... In that we need to include the Urls of the articles which are published from the last three days...

Comment: Then I assume you need to keep the news for three days. Your question is not clear, where you going to put this sitemap?

Comment: I am creating a news sitemap.. and I have read about the guidelines for news sitemap and there its stated that we can only submit the last three days published stories only... So I am not going to do the sitemap manually I will give a link to my database where it updates the sitemap for every three days... If I din't updated anything new in my database then what aould happen.. will the old links remain same or it will remove the old links and keep it as blank.

Comment: You are creating your sitemap for what purpose? To be used somewhere, where?